# Express.io can not emit events when routed from http request

Tags: express, socket.io

```
Here  i use those codes:
// Initial web request.
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    // Forward to an io route.
    req.io.route('hello')
})

app.io.route('hello', function(req) {
    //Here use emit
    req.io.emit("world","world");
})
```

it report an error as follow:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'emit'
at Object.hello (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/app.js:44:12)
at Manager.io.route (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/lib/index.coffee:65:29)
at Object.request.io.route (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/lib/index.coffee:143:29)
at /Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/app.js:39:12
at callbacks (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:160:37)
at param (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:134:11)
at pass (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:141:5)
at Router._dispatch (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:169:5)
at Object.router (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:32:10)
at next (/Users/wensonsmith/ProjectX/Server/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
```

req.io.respond is OK .

Broadcast is also have some problem.It can broadcast ,but it doesn't stop after broadcast.
it run for a long while ,then return nothing ,and no error messages.

My code is

```
// Initial web request.
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    // Forward to an io route.
    req.io.route('hello')
})

// Forward io route to another io route.
app.io.route('hello', function(req) {
    req.io.broadcast("world","world");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the code you're posting is the actual code, judging by the stack trace.

But apart from that: as far as I understand `express.io`, when you're forwarding an HTTP request to an io route, the io route should *always* send back a response with `respond`; otherwise, the HTTP request will stall.

So try this:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  req.io.route('hello');
});

app.io.route('hello', function(req) {
  // broadcast first...
  req.io.broadcast("world","world");
  // ...then send back an empty response
  req.io.respond();
});
```

Just to make sure: `req.io.broadcast` will *not* send the message back to the client that initiated the request. If you want that, use `app.io.broadcast` instead ([see docs](https://github.com/techpines/express.io/tree/master/examples#broadcasting)).

Comment: Yes! After add `req.io.respond()` it works well!  Thank you very much! ! By the way , do you known why the req has no method 'emit'??

Comment: @WensonSmith I would think it's called `req.io.emit()`

Answer (score 0):

Its only 50% answered ;) ::

**.respond** takes your arguments "directly" to **emit** them,
e.g.:

```
req.io.respond({hello: 'world'})
```